# connecting ajax and php not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

what is the problem of this code?
it is menu and page change by ajax with out refreshing the page, but its not working
it is my ajax code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.news').click(function give(id){
                $('#main-unit').text('Please Wait...');
                    var place= id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'pages/news.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'where='+place,
                        statusCode:{
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#main-unit').html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my html tags

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="news" onclick=\"give('news')\" href="#">news</a></li>
</ul>
```

and php code

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("basi")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    if($_POST['where']=='news'){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contents WHERE type = 0");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $title = $row['title'];
            $text = $row['text'];
            echo"
            <div class='title'><span>$title</span></div>
            <div class='content'>
            $text
            </div>
            ";
        }
    }
```

the information read from DB but dont return to html file.

Comment: what says the console?

Comment: nothing, it only shows "please Wait..." [$('#main-unit').text('Please Wait...');] then shows nothing

Comment: I mean the console for debugging, the one you get by pressing F12 on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your JavaScript. You're waiting for document ready and (incorrectly) binding a click event listener that isn't being used! Try:

```
<a class="news" onclick="give('news')" href="#">news</a>
```

with the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function give(id) {
        $('#main-unit').text('Please Wait...');
        var place = id;
        $.ajax({
            url:'pages/news.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'where='+place,
            statusCode:{
                success: function(data){
                    $('#main-unit').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

A better solution would be to separate HTML from JavaScript - remove the onclick attribute from your menu link, and use pure jQuery to select it and bind an event that calls give() when it is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.news').click(function(e) {
        give('news');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FTFY

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.news').click(function give(id){
                $('#main-unit').text('Please Wait...');
                    var place= id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'pages/news.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'where='+place,
                        //I believe your mistake was here
                        success: function(data){
                                $('#main-unit').html(data);
                         }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```